# Reading from datatable; how to trap error on last line

Tags: c#, loops, datatable, null

I have an application that reads an entire Excel file into a datatable. I need to retrieve subsets of data from this table into separate datatables. I do this by looping down the cells of the Excel table until I find a blank cell.

The problem is that the last line of the longest column of the Excel table (in other words, the last row of the Excel table) always errors out, with "There is no row at position " followed by whatever the last row of the longest column is.

Here is a scaled-down version of my code that gives me the error:

```
do {
        string MyString = dtExcel.Rows[i][11].ToString();
   } while (dt.Rows[i][11].ToString().Length > 0);
```

Where i is the row counter and [11] is the column I need to save. It works perfectly until the last row of the longest column, and then bombs out.

I've tried checking to see if dtExcel.Rows[i][11] is null, or if the ToString() length is zero, but I can't figure out how to trap this error because the mere act of trying to read it causes the error.

I guess my question is, is there a way of checking to see if this row even exists before I try to check it for null or turn it into a string, or whatever?

Hopefully this is clear. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where are you incrementing the row counter `i`? Is it before or after the line `string MyString = ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a while loop checking if the row is empty, use

```
for(int i=0;i < dt.Rows.Count ;i++){
     //...
}
```

to loop through the rows.
By doing that, it'll know when to stop in advance, and you will not get an
Index out of Bounds Exception

Answer (score 0):

Try reading your datatable this way:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach( var r in dt.AsEnumerable())
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(r[11])) break;

    sb.Append(r[11]);

}
return sb.ToString();
```